# Prestashop 1.7.x plugin stripe

Tags: prestashop, stripe-payments

I'm using prestashop with a stripe plugins for payments.
After checking configurations with the stripe support, we didn't found anything ..but the request sent appaear to be incomplete...

Did anybody have an idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have more detail of what you mean by 'incomplete,' that might help folks here help to troubleshoot with you

Comment: thanks for asking..i've contacted the stripe support... but waiting while a few days without any mouvement from them.

My problem is now.. the fileds on the cart are not displayed..and the console say an error with the publicKey...